# What is "armchair analysis sound"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases, rhetoric

I'm reading the famous question [XKCD #936: Short complex password, or long dictionary passphrase?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/6095/102733) on Security.SE. The last sentence confuses me:

> Am I missing something or is this *armchair analysis sound*?

It seems that OP meant "XKCD's analysis might be flawed", but I wonder how the phrase "armchair analysis sound" can express this meaning.

Comment: **armchair** is a noun used as an adjective, and its colloquial meaning is "lacking in procedural rigor, informal".  *Is this informal (not in any way rigorous) analysis on a firm foundation?*   **sound** =possessing integrity, not shaky, not falling apart.

Comment: @TRomano Gotcha! Is **analysis** used as adjective, too? I suppose there can be only one noun in this three-word phrase.

Comment: **analysis** is the (noun) subject of the predicate **is**.  **armchair** is a modifier of **analysis** (the kind of analysis) and **sound** is another adjective.  **sound** does not refer to the auditory phenomenon, but is related to German "Ge**sund**heit" and the English word "a**sund**er".  it means "possessing (physical) integrity, healthy, not feeble or coming apart in some way".  The opposite is **unsound**.

Comment: @TRomano WOW what a weird phrase it is! I've been learning English for over 15 years, and have never seen anything like this before. Are such expressions common in everyday English? (BTW: why not make your comments an answer?)

Comment: I didn't make it an answer because your question is based on a misunderstanding; it looks like three nouns in a row, but it is really {adjective}{noun}{adjective}.  I am sure you have seen many things analogous but did not recognize the similarity to this phrase.

Comment: @TRomano Thanks for pointing that out. I understand it now: it can be rephrase as *this armchair analysis may not be sound*.

Comment: Yes, the author is asking whether this informal analysis "holds water", which is a similar way of putting the question. The allusion in that "holds water" idiom is to a vessel which is either watertight (in which case it could be called "sound") or leaky.

Comment: *Is the table leg solid?*

Comment: *Is the speed boat wood?*

Comment: @TRomano Now I won't ask *what is "table leg solid" and "speed boat wood"?* :)

Comment: The list is unending :)  *Is the garden wall granite?*

Comment: @TRomano Similarly, *can you can a can as a canner can can a can?*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Armchair** is used as an adjective (modifies "Analysis"). 
**Analysis** is a noun.
**Sound** is an adjective here (modifies "Armchair Analysis").

> "Is this armchair analysis sound?"

Can also be written as....

> "Is this amateur analysis reasonable?"

"Armchair Analysis"  refers to an analysis coming from an onlooker observing from an armchair instead of someone actually involved in the field with real experience or expertise.  "Sound" has many dictionary definitions related to whole, healthy, reasonable, fair, or good.  I think of it as meaning "solid".   I didn't find an etymology for it, but I believe it's related to the fact that broken items make a different **sound** when you hit them, especially if they are made of metal, glass or ceramics.  If it has a nice sound you know it is sound (not broken).

Comment: Here’s your [etymology](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=sound): "free from special defect or injury," c. 1200, from Old English _gesund_ "sound, safe, having the organs and faculties complete and in perfect action," from Proto-Germanic _*sunda_-, from Germanic root _*swen-to_- "healthy, strong" (source also of Old Saxon _gisund_, Old Frisian _sund_, Dutch _gezond_, with connections in Indo-Iranian and Balto-Slavic. Meaning "right, correct, free from error" is from mid-15c._

Comment: Also note that "armchair" (as an idiom to mean something done from an armchair instead of doing the actual work) is used in more phrases than just this one. "Armchair referee" springs to mind, for someone judging a football match on TV.

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase

> is this armchair analysis *sound*?

means

> does this armchair analysis *make sense*?
>
> sound = based in scholarly thought or theory

as in

> He has **sound** judgement in deciding things
>   *He has good and fair judgment* in deciding things